# Appoint a unique registration code

Tags: php, md5

I have a registration form on my site for users to sign up to become members.

When they register their details are sent to the mysql database, and their email, name etc is all put in. they also get a unique registration code which is generated by random md5 on submit and this code is entered into the database as well as it being emailed to them.

The problem i am getting is each time a new user signs up a new code is generated but it re-writes over the previous code for all the other users in the database. What i want is for each users code to stay unique and for it not to re-write over the others each time a new user signs up, so I'm thinking that i need to edit my code to say

```
UPDATE `ptb_registrations` SET `registration_code` = '%s' 
    WHERE email = (whatever unique email the user enters)
```

any one got any ideas? thanks

```
<?php

/**
 * ShuttleCMS - A basic CMS coded in PHP.
 * random code - Used for allowing a user to reset password
 * 
 * @author Dan <dan@danbriant.com>
 * @version 0.0.1
 * @package ShuttleCMS
 */
define('IN_SCRIPT', true);
// Start a session
session_start();

/*
 * Generates registration code and puts it on database
 */

//Generate a RANDOM MD5 Hash for a code
$random_code=md5(uniqid(rand()));

//Take the first 8 digits and use them as the code we intend to email the user
$emailcode=substr($random_code, 0, 8);

//Encrypt $emailcode in MD5 format for the database
$registrationcode=($emailcode);

// Make a safe query
$query = sprintf("UPDATE `ptb_registrations` SET `registration_code` = '%s' ",
                    mysql_real_escape_string($registrationcode));

mysql_query($query)or die('Could not update members: ' . mysql_error());

?>
```

Comment: Are you missing a `WHERE` clause in your query? This reminds me of the time when my whole movie database consisted of nothing but "Ace Ventura - Pet Detective" :)

Comment: i think so, i basically need to find a way of setting a WHERE condition so that each time a new code is generated it does it just to the individual email if that makes sense, but because each users email will be different and typed in by the user I'm not sure how to code my WHERE clause?

Comment: yes you have the solution in your answer, you do need to use a `where` cluase in your SQL

Answer (score 1):

In your MySQL query you are not putting a where clause to restricted it to just that new user. You are updating "ALL" users by virtue of the fact you have not restricted it.

Your code doesn't look complete because you're not including the bit about the registration, but I'll assume that's handled ok.

Then you want to update your query to be something like

UPDATE `ptb_registrations` SET `registration_code` = '%s' WHERE user_id = '%s'

Obviously replacing with the right values for your schema.

Comment: ok this looks good. the only problem i have is that when the user registers there is currently no user_id being set up for them, they're all just 0. is there a way i can get my registration.php script to generate a sequential user_id on submit in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my question: **why don't You just generate that code at the time of registering the user?** That way You would only do a `INSERT INTO` without need of doing another `UPDATE` query.

The process could be like this

- get the user credentials
- generate the unique key
- store all into the DB
- send an email containing that unique key for approval of email address
- all done

Hmm?

Answer (score 0):

by running

```
UPDATE `ptb_registrations` SET `registration_code`
```

you are updating all users, you're missing the `WHERE` clause:

```
UPDATE `ptb_registrations` SET `registration_code` = "safkhsakjfdha" 
  WHERE `email`='bla@bla.bla'
```

beside than that all the rest looks good, assuming all the variables have values.